# System.NullPointerException parent child relationship

Tags: apex, visualforce, account, master-detail

I have a child object of Parent Account name Vendor .

I want to create multiple vendor on one account record.

I have created master detail relationship between these two.

When i want to save(insert) the account i am getting the following error. 
at the line  **c.id=idey;**

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Code snippet in which error is as follows

```
public PageReference saveAccount(){
        Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(acct, false);
        Id idey=sr.getId();
        List<Vendor__c> contactList=new List<Vendor__c>();
        for(WrapperClass wc:lContacts){
            Vendor__c c=new Vendor__c();
        c.Name__c=wc.c.Name__c;
        c.Email__c=wc.c.Email__c;
        //c.Account__r.accountId =idey;
       c.id=idey;
        contactList.add(c);
        }
        insert contactList;
        PageReference p = new PageReference('/001/o');


        return p;
    }
```

Can you help me out 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Change c.id=idey to c.Account__c=idey and try

Comment: I posted the comment as Answer. If the solution worked for you please accept and upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `c.id=idey` to `c.Account__c=idey`

Reason

Assigning id of account idey to id of vendor will throw error.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify ID in insert call. Since you are looking to use Parent's id. It should be something like below -

```
public PageReference saveAccount(){
        Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(acct, false);
        Id idey=sr.getId();
        List<Vendor__c> contactList=new List<Vendor__c>();
        for(WrapperClass wc:lContacts){
            Vendor__c c=new Vendor__c();
        c.Name__c=wc.c.Name__c;
        c.Email__c=wc.c.Email__c;
        c.Account__c=idey;
        contactList.add(c);
        }
        insert contactList;
        PageReference p = new PageReference('/001/o');


        return p;
    }
```